# Add line break to a long string after every 4th instance of delimiter

Tags: excel, ms-word, formatting, delimiter, line-breaks

I have a super long string that is delimited by the character '|' in microsoft word.

Am i able to add a line break after every 4th instance of the string?

E.g.

Original String:

John|21|M|Student|Andy|25|M|Teacher|Sherry|22|F|Student|Nicholas|21|M|Student|Daphne|19|F|Student|......

Desired Output:

John|21|M|Student

Andy|25|M|Teacher

Sherry|22|F|Student

Nicholas|21|M|Student

Daphne|19|F|Student

....

I only have access to microsoft word, excel, notepad, wordpad.

Sorry about my limited access to programs. I suspect i need to use excel vba or some form of "search and replace regex" in word.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your 4th column always Student or Teacher?

Comment: No.. it is a random string

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

In Word:

- Paste your text
- Search and replace
- Select the "Use wildcards" check box
- Search for: `(*)|(*)|(*)|(*)|`
- Replace with: `\1|\2|\3|\4^p`
- Replace all
- Output

  John|21|M|Student
  Andy|25|M|Teacher
  Sherry|22|F|Student
  Nicholas|21|M|Student
  Daphne|19|F|Student

  Explanation:
  (*) defines a search term, () defines the borders, * is the expression, i.e. none or more characters
  /1 is the first search term, i.e. it returns the characters from the first search term
  ^p is the expression for a new line
  **Reference:**

  ### [Microsoft help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-wildcard-characters-to-find-or-replace-text-610e37dc-bb2f-4a8b-8fa5-aa991160eafb)

Comment: Thanks for ur help